# Omxplayer fill mode not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, omxplayer

Working on a video project for raspberry pi.  Trying to get video to fill entire screen.  When I call `omxplayer videofile.mp4 --aspect-mode fill` it plays fine.  However when I call it in my program the argument for the aspect ratio is not working.

```
import pygame
import sys
from time import sleep
from omxplayer import OMXPlayer

pygame.joystick.init()

_joystick_right = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
_joystick_right.init()
_joystick_left = pygame.joystick.Joystick(1)
_joystick_left.init()
pygame.init()
done = False
button = ''
controller = ''
player = ''
path = 'hankvids/'


movies = [
 'vid1.mp4',
 'vid2.mp4',
]

quit_video = False

while done==False:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
      button = event.button
      controller = event.joy
      if quit_video == True:
        if button == 0 and controller == 0:
          player.quit()
          quit()
        else:
          if player.is_playing():
            player.load(path + movies[controller], pause=False)
       else:
         quit_video = True
         player = OMXPlayer(path + movies[controller], args=["-b --aspect-mode fill"], pause=False)
```

Comment: Should it be `--aspect-mode` or `--aspect-ratio`? You have two different commands in code and in your question.

Comment: whoops, --aspect-mode, description is a typo

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the command into words: `args=["-b", "--aspect-mode",  "fill"],`. Alternatively you can pass your CLI string to `shlex` to split the args string for you.